# Is there any function to convert long to int in php?

Tags: php

I have this long number `2241574459` , how can i convert this to string or readable number ?Is there any php functions ?

Comment: It's quite readable right now. What do you want as result?

Comment: thats actually some 3 or 4 digit number

Comment: So what your "number" means? You've said it's `long` data type.

Comment: actually , Server returns this 2241574459 , but that's some 3 or 4 digit number..i have no idea how to decode it

Comment: And I have no idea what your string means. You can try [unpack](http://us1.php.net/unpack) - but that's just guess

Comment: have u encountered some kinda encoded number that looks like 2241574459 ?

Comment: Yes, thousands a day (surprise: __any__ data is represented with bits, which can be written as sequence of decimal number, and, therefore, your string could be anything)

Comment: Bob's your uncle [`echo long2ip(2241574459);`](https://eval.in/72290)

Comment: This is definitely not a 3 or 4 digit number. Actually, the data your server returns seems not to be what you expect.

Comment: Isn't it clear? He wants "twentytwobillionfourhundredfifteenmillionsevenhundredfourtyfourthousandandninetyfive"

Comment: @DamienOvereem : ha ha lol

Answer (score 3):

I know exactly how to accomplish this common task:

```
$variable = preg_replace(
    "/\d{5,}/", 
    "string or readable number", 
    $variable
);
```

This will replace all 5+ digit numbers with string or readable number.

*Moral of the story: Make your question clear -- how can anyone know what that integer represents? This is actually the only valid answer to it, as stupid as it is.*

Answer (score 1):

```
$text="2241574459";
$zahl=(int) $text;
```

Unless I misunderstand your question.